# Will dockerizing the application increase the startup time of application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, containers

We have a java application which was running without docker before. Recently we dockerized the application, startup time is more than before. So I just want to ask will dockerizing the application increase the startup time of application?

Comment: Depends on the resources the server/vm has.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a significant difference, but you do have the docker layer to deal with and the docker engine itself might have fewer resources such as CPU and memory and filesystem drivers which could have some effect.

Answer (score 0):

Normally not really as a container is just a toolset that use many kernel and linux tools to works.

But if you use Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows, you may see a performance hit as theses 2 solutions use a small VM to run and, by default, do not use all your CPU core and RAM available.

And, if you are on Windows or Mac and you use bind mount volume, the performance could decrease even more as the IO are not as fast as without docker.